# How to push array inside array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need inject multiples data in array, to use another array but when I test  this data with  an alert only show [Object, object], not show the data.

How can I add or push this data in array ?

```
var promos = [];
listSlider.each(function () {
    var myID=this.id;
    var myName = $(this).find( "div.info h3" ).text();
    var creative = $(this).find( "h1 span" ).text();
    var position=myID.split("-")[1];

    promos.push({
        'id'        : myID,
        'name'      : myName,
        'creative'  : creative,
        'position'  : position
    });

}); 
alert(promos[2]);
```

Comment: promotions? You have never declared this variable.

Comment: *"[Object, object]"* - don't use `alert` on javascript objects (it's ok for basic types like numbers or strings).   Use `console.log(promotions)`

Comment: You are pushing your object in `promos`. What is `promotions` here?

Comment: In case you want to use `alert` for your array you can use `alert(JSON.stringify(promotions[2]))`.

Comment: alert show `[Object, object]` means there are data in the variables. alert do not display data of the objects. You can replace alert `console.log` and share the result here.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I´ve edited "promotions" for "promos" and I´ve solve this with  the response from freedomn-m and Hassan Imam thank you